# Existence of particular/specialized halting oracles

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem

It is known that there **does not exists** an oracle $H$ which given any pair $(M,I)$ where $M$ is a machine and $I$ is an input (possibly still a machine) to have $H(M(I)) = YES$ if $M(I)$ halts and $H(M(I)) = NO$ if $M(I)$ does not halt. This was proven by Turing. However, this can be shortly written as
$$ \not\exists H \hspace{0.5cm} \forall M,I \hspace{0.5cm} H(M(I)) = \begin{cases} YES, \hspace{0.3cm}M(I)  \text{  halts }\\ NO, \hspace{0.4cm} M(I) \text{ doesn not halt}\end{cases}$$

But is it possible to have the following:
$$ \forall M,I \hspace{0.5cm} \exists H_{M,I} \hspace{0.5cm} H_{M,I}(M(I)) = \begin{cases} YES, \hspace{0.3cm}M(I)  \text{  halts }\\ NO, \hspace{0.4cm} M(I) \text{ doesn not halt}\end{cases}$$

Comment: This is trivially true. The machine $H_{M,I}$ doesn't even have to consider its input.

Comment: An *oracle* usually signifies an arbitrary function. What Turing rules out is a *computable* oracle $H$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Given a machine $M$ and input $I$, one of the two things happens:

1. $M(I)$ halts.
2. $M(I)$ does not halt.

We may not be able to predict or compute which of these happens, but one and only one happens simply by rules of *classical* logic.

Now to show that $H_{M,I}$ exists we consider two cases:

1. If $M(I)$ halts then $H_{M,I}$ exists because we can take it to be a machine that immediately halts and outputs "yes".
2. If $M(I)$ does not halt then $H_{M,I}$ exists because we can take it to be a machine that immediately halts and outputs "no".

Note: we proved existence of $H_{M,I}$, but we did not give a way of computing $H_{M,I}$ from $M$ and $I$, which is impossible as that would give us the halting oracle (exercise).

So, what Yuval said.

Comment: Well, I thought it is implicitly understood (from the definition of $H_{M,I}$) that $H_{M,I}$ should always halt ...

Comment: You have to halt to output something, aren't you ?

Comment: Oops, fixed it.

Comment: Thank you for your time! But, I do not know how being able to compute it, for the particular case $M,I$, would give the halting oracle (which is for all $M,I$)!  Can you hint me in the direction?

Comment: No, I am not going to hint you in the right direction only 30 minutes after I posted my answer. You should get used to thinking about a problem longer than that. If after two days of thinking you don't see the answer, then I think it would be appropriate to get a hint. You really need to try yourself and be persistent.